# Python, Pandas processing df

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am currently learing python and I want to do the following:

I got a pandas dataframe:

```
Time                  A       B       ...   Z
2018-10-17 16:49:56  NaN     NaN      ...  16.28
2018-10-17 22:40:36  NaN     'String' ...  NaN
2018-10-20 01:37:32  NaN     NaN      ...  25.00
2018-10-20 11:30:39  15.0    NaN      ...  NaN
2018-10-20 12:07:04  NaN     NaN      ...  NaN
```

and I would like to transform it into something like this:

```
Time                  A       B       ...   Z
2018-10-17 16:49:56  NaN     NaN      ...  16.28
2018-10-17 22:40:36  NaN     'String' ...  16.28
2018-10-20 01:37:32  NaN     'String' ...  25.00
2018-10-20 11:30:39  15.0    'String' ...  25.00
2018-10-20 12:07:04  15.0    'String' ...  25.00
```

Where I always carry the value into the next row, except the row has a new item.

If I can do this, the next step would be to replace the string with a floating value which I can do with `df = df.replace('string', value)` and convert the Time into a numeric which contains the number of seconds `t.hour * 3600 + t.minute * 60 + t.second` would be my first options with the the module `datetime` . Currently I am unsure if this is the best way to go, because I know, there is `pandas.to_datetime`.

```
Time                  A       B       ...   Z
2018-10-17 16:49:56  NaN     NaN      ...  16.28+0
2018-10-17 22:40:36  NaN     value+0  ...  16.28+1
2018-10-20 01:37:32  NaN     value+1  ...  25.00+0
2018-10-20 11:30:39  15.0    value+2  ...  25.00+1
2018-10-20 12:07:04  15.0    value+3  ...  25.00+2
```

The Number of colums and rows is variable.

My Idea would be, to build a new dataframe and extract and compare the data with the old dataframe row by row, but I don't know exactly how to do it and maybe there is a more elegant way.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ffill` [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html)

```
df = df.ffill()

          Time           A        B           Z
0   2018-10-17 16:49:56  NaN     NaN        16.28
1   2018-10-17 22:40:36  NaN    'String'    16.28
2   2018-10-20 01:37:32  NaN    'String'    25.00
3   2018-10-20 11:30:39  15.0   'String'    25.00
4   2018-10-20 12:07:04  15.0   'String'    25.00
```